# TypeScript: initialize class with type keys

Tags: typescript, class, types

I'm certainly losing it.

I've got a type here:

```js
type Bug = 'hairy' | 'scary' | 'cute' | 'ugly' // say, there are hundreds of types of bugs
```

Next, I've got a class, and I want to initialize some stuff there:

```js
class MeadowWithBugs {
  [key: keyof Bug]: number // <--- AAAAAAA!!! 
  constructor(){
    this.hairy = 1
    this.cute = 100
    // this.anyOtherKindOfBugFromBugType, but with autocomplete from the Bug type
  }
  // ...the rest of the bugs stuff
}
```

Obviously, it doesn't work like this: `[key: keyof Bug]: number` upsets TypeScript in more ways than one.

I tried pretty much everything:

- using `const Bug = [...]` and then `type Bugs = typeof Bug[number]`
- using `interface Bug { [key: string]: number }` and then declaring `const Bugs: Bug = { ugly: 2, ... }`
- trying all sorts of wizardry with `[key in Bugs]: number`, etc.
- going for a walk

Clearly, I'm doing something very, very wrong. The end result is always the same: it's either `An index signature parameter type must be 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or a template literal type.` or `An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.` Basically, I'm running in circles here.

What did work was initializing `class` with  `[key: keyof typeof Bug]: number`, but it allows *any* string to be a kind of bug, and no autocomplete :(

What I really want is to easily initialize this `class` with all keys from the `Bug` type, and have these keys available for autocomplete on `this` keyword in the constructor. Is it too much to ask?..

Comment: If this is dynamic, you'd still have to initialize the values somehow. How do you intend to do that? Usually this is a hard data model to manage, and if you could change it to something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wk081w) then you life will be a lot easier.

Comment: @alexwayne Ah, yeah, it’s kind of a given how this dynamic list is generated elsewhere, and how I need to assign these bugs to the initialized “keys”. Making some of them optional is the next step.
.
I guess, in part, I’m trying to avoid endless lists during initialization like [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgrgcygXigcgBYEMCWAnENKAH3QGcBjLAo0tCuYCW9RAG0KgHouoysQAGijAMEPNGrQMcAHYATCfLJQA9gDMR4CCo1QARohWA+DcDNewChzFNljIqAshCzzVAdwDqOUfAQqA3uZQUNj4IABcULJwALb64oF8VAQRUbHxQQxMKTFxeAnsIAD82Wl5CRSqsmTAeHAUwKp4ABQAlAFBQaI4ZAB0IQQoUACMCZ0Y3T2Z0KgATKMi472U1CCDAKwJAL7mm0A)